# When client has finished it's code, the socket server shutdowns. How to stop it from stopping?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to use Socket in python and I currently have an issue where I can get it to connect, but I want my socket server to stay open after the client has sent what it is supposed to send. I can succesfully send something but after that is done the whole server is shutdown. I want it to stay open so a client can connect again at any point.

My client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.0.127", 12345))

f = open("bce7d09d-66ce-46ca-979e-777c4cbc0cd1.json", "wb")

while True:
    datas = s.recv(1024)
    while datas:
        f.write(datas)
        datas = s.recv(1024)
    f.close()
socket.shutdown()
print("Done receiving")
```

My server.py

```
import socket
import subprocess
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.0.127", 12345))

s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

f = open("bce7d09d-66ce-46ca-979e-777c4cbc0cd1.json", "rb")
datas = f.read(1024)

while datas:
    c.send(datas)
    datas = f.read(1024)
f.close()
print("Done sending...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `s.accept()` is a blocking call, you can do:

`while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    ...`

to continue accepting new socket connection for the server.

Comment: Seems to do the job, however now i'm experiencing that the client is stuck and is never shutting down. Any idea?

Comment: Because you have a while True for client that keeps listening to the server

Comment: Even if I insert `break` into the code then it just keeps running.

Comment: You have 2 `while` loop, also `s.recv` is a blocking call as well, so it is going to wait for the server to send something

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `accept` in a loop:

```
import socket
import subprocess
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.0.127", 12345))

s.listen(10)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('{} connected.'.format(addr))
    with open("bce7d09d-66ce-46ca-979e-777c4cbc0cd1.json", "rb") as f:
        datas = f.read(1024)
        while datas:
            c.send(datas)
            datas = f.read(1024)
        print("Done sending...")
```